# Download or clone only a branch in git and not the entire tree

Tags: git, linux-kernel, kernel

Cloning linux kernel code from Torvalds git account, the code size runs into GBs. possibly, it is downloading all branch code. is there anyway i can download only the code of a particular tag.

i can do,

```
git clone https://github.com/torvalds/linux
git checkout -t v3.13
```

but, i don't want all the trunk & branch code sitting in my local.

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick:

```
git clone --branch v3.13 git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git
```

Alternatively what I generally do (as I can move freely switch between versions)

```
git fetch linux-next
git fetch --tags linux-next

     * [new tag]         v3.18      -> v3.18
     * [new tag]         v3.18-rc3  -> v3.18-rc3
     * [new tag]         v3.18-rc4  -> v3.18-rc4
     * [new tag]         v3.18-rc5  -> v3.18-rc5
     * [new tag]         v3.18-rc6  -> v3.18-rc6
     * [new tag]         v3.18-rc7  -> v3.18-rc7
     * [new tag]         v3.19-rc1  -> v3.19-rc1
     * [new tag]         v3.19-rc2  -> v3.19-rc2

git checkout -b my_branch  v3.18
```

Answer (score 1):

Use This Command to clone repositories:

```
  git clone <repo_url> --branch <tag_name> --single-branch
```

Use --single-branch option to only clone history leading to tip of the tag. This saves a lot of unnecessary code from being cloned.